# just like we have int8 in python to represent integer with 8 bits, can we represent integer in python less than 8 bit?

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to store integer numbers from -30 to 30 in python variable with int8, but I still want to reduce the integer bit size.. let say 6 bit is it possible I can create n bit integer variable where n can be from 1 to 32?

I tried this:

```
import numpy as np
a=np.int8(30)
print(a.nbytes)
>>1 bytes
```

I expect the output to be something like this:

```
import numpy as np
a=np.int6(30)

>>bitsize of a 6
```

Comment: For a single value, no; an `int6` would still need at least a byte of memory, since the byte is the fundamental unit of addressable memory. That isn't to say that a *collection* of `int6` values couldn't be packed into less memory than an equal number of `int8` values.

Comment: not only that if you want that type of precision then python isn't what you should be using.